# drbd module setup ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: command-line-interface, ubuntu-10.04, drbd

I am giving the following command.

> sudo apt-get install drbd8-utils drbd8-module-source \
>     build-essential module-assistant

and when I do, the response I get is

> Note, selecting drbd8-source instead of drbd8-module-source
>
> drbd8-source is already the newest version

Then when I go to install drbd using this command

> module-assistant auto-install drbd8

A GUI pops up and says that I am missing "something" (which I am assuming is the module since everything else installs correctly)

I'm following the guide from drbd.org, so I'm fairly certain that I have all of the pre-requisites installed. But I am relatively unfamiliar with linux so if I am missing something, I'd be happy to know what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just installed it on a 10.10 virtual machine doing

```
navaho@navaho-laptop:~$ apt-get install drbd8-utils
navaho@navaho-laptop:~$ modprobe drbd
navaho@navaho-laptop:~$ lsmod |grep drbd

drbd                  241864  0 
lru_cache               5950  1 drbd
```

I know that the documentation says otherwise, but that's the easiest way in my experience.

You can then review and edit the global conf and create the resource res in /etc/drbd.d according to the plan you have in mind.